# Select rows with same customer id but different transaction id in the same table?

Tags: sql

Every single item sold will come to a new row with date, transaction id, customer id, product name and quantity. I want to find out customers who have made at least 2 separate transactions in August.

Thanks a lot!

Table:

| Date | transaction_id | customer_id | product_name | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-05 10:44:59.000 | 5-123 | 888 | A | 1 |
| 2022-08-05 10:44:59.000 | 5-123 | 888 | A | 1 |
| 2022-08-05 18:32:22.000 | 5-179 | 174 | ZZ | 1 |
| 2022-08-06 10:32:22.000 | 6-264 | 223 | QA | 1 |
| 2022-08-06 10:32:52.000 | 6-264 | 223 | QB | 1 |
| 2022-08-06 12:57:12.000 | 6-365 | 379 | A | 1 |
| 2022-08-07 20:16:38.000 | 7-974 | 888 | V | 1 |
| 2022-08-08 17:48:11.000 | 8-276 | 732 | R | 1 |
| 2022-08-09 13:29:43.000 | 9-390 | 623 | G | 1 |
| 2022-08-10 09:33:57.000 | 10-862 | 623 | TT | 1 |
| 2022-08-11 16:23:31.000 | 11-348 | 623 | XD | 1 |

Expected result:

| Date | transaction_id | customer_id | product_name | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-05 10:44:59.000 | 5-123 | 888 | A | 1 |
| 2022-08-05 10:44:59.000 | 5-123 | 888 | A | 1 |
| 2022-08-07 20:16:38.000 | 7-974 | 888 | V | 1 |
| 2022-08-09 13:29:43.000 | 9-390 | 623 | G | 1 |
| 2022-08-10 09:33:57.000 | 10-862 | 623 | TT | 1 |
| 2022-08-11 16:23:31.000 | 11-348 | 623 | XD | 1 |

Comment: What is the datatype of Date column, and why you don't use full date format (including year)?

Comment: @ahmed it's timestamp data format which is: 2022-08-05 10:44:59.000, I updated the data

Comment: What DBMS you are using?

Comment: @ahmed how to check it? I am using DBEAVER to extract data, the DBMS should be Mysql? thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `Exists` with correlated subquery as the following:

```
Select T.Date_, T.transaction_id, T.customer_id, T.product_name, T.qty
From table_name T
Where Exists(Select 1 From table_name D 
             Where D.customer_id = T.customer_id And
                   D.transaction_id <> T.transaction_id
             )
And T.Date_ Between '2022-08-01 00:00:00' And '2022-08-31 00:00:00'
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c89fccbc9fbedf5d3a7608599b65cb1).

Comment: what if the above data  is from a CTE table? How can I use the cte table to form another 2 table? table T and table D?

Comment: It will be the same, just replace the table name with the CTE name, check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=817f327b094e1e6fe957e65fea321b19

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the only customer_id whose made more than on transaction, use the below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*),CUSTOMER_ID FROM TRANSACTION 
WHERE DATE between "2022-08-01" AND "2022-08-31" group by 
TRANSACTION_ID HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```

If you want to fetch more detailed data then use the below query.

```
SELECT DATE,TRANSACTION_ID,CUSTOMER_ID,PRODUCT_NAME FROM TRANSACTION 
WHERE DATE between "2022-08-01" AND "2022-08-31" 
group by TRANSACTION_ID ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID
```